# How do you get every user that reacted to a message in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to grab the userid or equivalent of every user that reacted to a message. My code looks something like this, and in the output I recieve, I can see the userid's. But I've got no idea how to grab them. Any ideas? I've tried stuff like collection.users but I can't seem to get anything working.

Here is my code,

```
const sumSeconds = 5;
const filter = reaction => {
      return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
    }
    message.channel.send("React with  for a chance to win").then( message => {
      message.react("");
      message.awaitReactions(filter,{max:50,time:sumSeconds*1000}).then(collection => {
        console.log(collection);
      }).catch();
    }).catch();
```

This is what collection outputs whenever I print it

```
Collection [Map] {
  '' => MessageReaction {
    message: Message {
      channel: [TextChannel],
      deleted: false,
      id: '672835948395216429',
      type: 'DEFAULT',
      content: 'React with  for a chance to win',
      author: [ClientUser],
      member: [GuildMember],
      pinned: false,
      tts: false,
      nonce: null,
      system: false,
      embeds: [],
      attachments: Collection [Map] {},
      createdTimestamp: 1580486989843,
      editedTimestamp: null,
      reactions: [Collection [Map]],
      mentions: [MessageMentions],
      webhookID: null,
      hit: null,
      _edits: []
    },
    me: true,
    count: 2,
    users: Collection [Map] {
      '671732735845016837' => [ClientUser],
      '181250039684617312' => [User]
    },
    _emoji: ReactionEmoji { reaction: [Circular], name: '', id: null }
  }
}
```

What I would like to extract is this part

```
users: Collection [Map] {
      '671732735845016837' => [ClientUser],
      '181250039684617312' => [User]
    }
```

Please help c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `collection.first().users`:

```js
const sumSeconds = 5;
const filter = reaction => {
      return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
};
message.channel.send("React with  for a chance to win").then( message => {
      message.react("");
      message.awaitReactions(filter,{max:50,time:sumSeconds*1000}).then(collection => {
        console.log(collection.first().users); // Collection of users
      }).catch(() => {});
}).catch(() => {});
```